NPSP - Error while clearing batch reference in data import
When trying to clear the batch reference in a data import, I am getting this error
Error saving record: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: npsp.TDTM_DataImport: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object.
With the following process:

Open an NPSP Data Import record.
Populate the NPSP Data Import Batch field (npsp__NPSP_Data_Import_Batch__c) with an existing batch
Save the record
Clear the NPSP Data Import Batch field.

Is there any way to remove the reference to data import batch from the data import?
Thank you
